# slide subsequent divs placed one below the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to slide the divs that are placed one below the other, but i don't know how to select the next div once it the div on top of it slided.

In this example once the red div as slided how do i select the blue div to slide away. I need to select the top div as for every div there will  be a function associated with a keycode.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ddpqsc

```js
$(document).ready(function() {            
  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
        arrow = {
          left: 37,
          up: 38,
          right: 39,
          down: 40
        };
    switch (keyCode) {
      case arrow.left: 
        $(".red").animate({ "left": "-100%" }, "slow");
        break;
      case arrow.right: 
        $(".red").animate({ "left": "0%" }, "slow");
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i understood is that you want the divs to slide based on the right or the left arrow key pressed. Here is what you need. Use a active class(class can have any name need not be active, i have used active) that will help you get the current on top div and using that you can get the next and previous div and slide them accordingly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){            
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
        arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
     var currentDiv=$('.active');
        switch (keyCode) {
            
            case arrow.left:
                if (currentDiv.next("div").length>0) {
                    currentDiv.animate({ "left": "-100%" }, "slow");
                    currentDiv.next("div").addClass("active");
                    currentDiv.removeClass("active");
                }
                
            break;
            
            case arrow.right:
                if (currentDiv.prev("div").length>0) {
                    currentDiv.prev("div").animate({ "left": "0%" }, "slow");
                    currentDiv.prev("div").addClass("active");
                    currentDiv.removeClass("active");
                }
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.active{
z-index:100;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}


.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
 }
  
  .green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red active"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8ddpqsc/3/)
This code will work irrespective of the number of divisions present.

For more info on `.next()` and `.prev()` have a look at

1. https://api.jquery.com/next/
2. https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Well this solves partially, but the reason i need to find out which div is on the top is.. say if the current div is said to be blue then if (current div== blue) then for case arrow.left (function()); case arrow.down(function()).such that every current div will have a function based on a keycode. Hence i need a way to find out which div is on the top

Comment: i think i m not getting completely what you are trying. Correct me if i m wrong. What the scenario is that each div will have different handlers for right and left arrow key press and you want that handler to execute instead of the way it is right now. And also can you please update the fiddle according to what exactly the scenario will be. I will be able to help better.

Comment: At first the red div will be the div on top. On pressing the left arrow the blue div will be visible. At this point my current div will the blue div. 
For the blue div i want to keep three functions such that on left keypress the green will appear and on right the red will appear and ON down the blue div will slide to the top revealing another div. I am sorry if this isnt clear enough

Comment: ok i got it now. So what you want is that apart from the sliding right and left on key press, you want there should be a handler for down or up arrow key press and that should slide the current infocus/on top div up or down to show more divs right. So you basically want slide the divs horizontally as well as vertically. Can you please update your fiddle with the html markup for both vertical and horizontal  divs (So that i can just get an idea how you DOM will look like.)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a counter and an array.

First you can create a counter by setting the variable of `i`:

```
var i = 0;
```

The `i` variable would have to be declared after `$(document).ready(function(){` as if you did it in the `keyup` listener it would be overwritten every time you press a key which is not what you want.

Then you can create an array with all your div classes like so:

```
var divs = [".red", ".blue", ".green"];
```

You can cycle through each div using a counter by adding and removing from it depending if your moving your sliding the div back onto the pile or off the pile.

So then in your switch statement you would have something like this:

```
case arrow.left:

    if(i < divs.length-1){
        $(divs[i]).animate({"left": "-100%"}, "slow");
        i++;
    }

break;

case arrow.right: 
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
        $(divs[i]).animate({"left": "0%"}, "slow");
    }

break;
```

If you take a look at this jsfiddle you can see this working with full code: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ddpqsc/5/

Comment: Is there way in which i could use the counter to find which div is currrently on top. because i have functions based on the top div

Comment: @RakeshRenzous By on the top do you mean the div you are currently looking at? Or do you mean check if you are looking at the top div? If you mean to check what div you are currently looking at you can use the counter by  adding  `console.log("You are looking at " +divs[i]);` under both `i++;` and `i--;`. The `divs[i]` gives you the class of the current div.

Comment: The div that i am currently looking at

Comment: @RakeshRenzous yeah then you can use what I recommended in the last comment. If you want to check for example if you are looking at the blue do you can do something like this. 

`if(divs[i] == ".blue"){// Do code}`. You wold have to place this under the `i++;` and `i--;` lines of code. I suggest you make a function which does a check for each div and call the function whenever you want to use it again. Take a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ddpqsc/8/